# "az pipelines runs artifact download" fails with error "Artifact was found, but is of type 'Container'"

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

"az pipelines runs artifact download --run-id 10976432 --artifact-name "Android/Android" --path "c:/foo/" fails with error "Artifact with name 'Android' was found, but is of type 'Container'"

I publish artifacts from our build runs to several different repositories like NPM, Nuget, PyPi, CoCoPods, and this process requires "two factor authentication", so at least for now it will remain a manual post build process for us.

But even though this is a manual process, I want to automate as much of it as I can, e.g. automating the download a dozen or more build run artifacts to a local staging directory that I then use to publish from.

I have found several community post that have done this with CURL and the REST apis, but I want to get this working with the az devops extention.

As far as I can tell from the azure extension this command should work, but it does not!
How can I download build run artifacts (not public feed artifacts), so that I can manually or automatically publish them outside for the normal DevOps pipeline?

Thanks,

Brian.

Comment: cross linking to my matching GitHub issue report...

https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli-extensions/issues/1466

Answer (score 2):

> "Artifact with name 'Android' was found, but is of type 'Container'"

I guess the publish task you are using is [Publish Build Artifacts task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops), right? If yes, as the message shown, we indeed does not support download `container` type artifacts until now.

**As of today, you can just download artifacts of `type -'Pipeline Artifact'` from `az cli`.**

In order to use `az cli` to download artifacts successfully , if possible, please go replace the publish task with [Publish Pipeline Artifact task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#publishing-artifacts):

```
- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  inputs:
    targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'
    artifact: 'AzLogicApp'
    publishLocation: 'pipeline'
```

Now, you will see you can succeed to download the artifact with `az cli`.